# Cannot click my floating action button which is above a scroll view

Tags: android, android-scrollview, floating-action-button

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` and inside it, two `FloatingActionButton` and below them a `ScrollView`.

The problem is that even though I can see my `FloatingActionButtons` on screen I cannot click them. I suspect that's because all `onTouch` events are being handled from `ScrollView`

Here is my layout xml (which is probably pretty bad so any tips are welcome):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Note: that 80dp padding is:
         main_padding + fab_size + 8dp = 80dp 
              16dp    +    56dp  + 8dp = 80dp
         and it was the only way I could think to add padding
         between my FABs 
         I tried to use app:layout_anchor but my 2
         FABs had no padding between them... -->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        style="@style/RefreshFab"
        android:id="@+id/fab_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        style="@style/SendFab"
        android:id="@+id/fab_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <!-- Much stuff here, text views, spinners etc.. -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you wrap each FAB inside its own FrameLayout?

Comment: @McAdam331 oh.. You're right it is redundant. I removed the two frame layouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is because each item is laid out in a CoordinatorLayout in the same order it is written in the xml. By that logic, the FloatingActionButtons are each placed on the screen and then the LinearLayout on top of them, so I would expect the click is being overriden by the LinearLayout.

Rearrange your XML to place the FloatingActionButtons *last*, so that they are 'on top', so to speak, of your layout. Then they will detect your click listeners just fine.

I think the problem will persist since each FloatingActionButton is wrapped inside of a FrameLayout with match_parent dimensions. I do not believe you need these FrameLayouts, but you can simply put the FloatingActionButtons inside of the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I put them below the `LinearLayout` and it worked! I thought that elements that are higher on xml will appear on top of the lower ones. Apparently it's the other way around. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TheCrafter No problem! Glad I was able to clarify that for you.

Comment: @AshishMathur Glad to help!